# Subversion display custom message to client upon update

Tags: svn, hook, message

Let an svn repository be shared among many users. let the svn repository be used to store versions of a database creation script and some other non-code objects. is there a way to display a custom message (ie:that can be read from a file) upon update?
example:
i am working on $project
i change the class encapsulating database queries so that i am also adding a single attribute in a database table -> i need to change the test-database creation script so that it contains the new value
i modify the file post-update-msg (called, i suppose, by the post-update svn hook) by writing in it:

> WARNING: the some_db_script changed, you need to generate the test db again

and each client, upon performing an

> svn update

command,  gets something like:

> user@box:~/code/svn-working-copy$ svn update
>   U    many other stuff
>   U    scripts/some_db_script
>   Updated to revision n+1
>   WARNING: the some_db_script changed, you need to generate the test db again
>   user@box:~/code/svn-working-copy$

can it be done via svn hooks? is there another more elegant/better way of doing it?
thanks in advance

Comment: The dev who didn't tidy up is at fault...leaving src in a bad state and expecting it to be correct downstream due to a message is asking for problems.

Comment: @Aaron : i understand that it's not a correct way of developing something, the script change should have been planned and added to the development cycle, but sometime you just have to cope with this kind of thing, expecially in a small group of devels

Comment: If you have no luck here, give http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewForumSummary.do?dsForumId=4061 a whirl, plenty of folks there to help you accomplish your goals and are very knowledgeable on SVN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In subversion only terms it is not possible, because subversion provides **no post-update-hooks**

So you will rely on 3rd party tools(maybe your own checkout script?) which should examine the updated files and will display such a message.

I want to point out, that **TortoiseSVN** supports such post-update hooks (see instructions [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks)),
however you are directly dependent on TortoiseSVN (not so bad, if you ask me) but cannot incorporate other subversion clients(commandline, or IDE-based tools). Also You need to "deploy" these client hooks (as the name said) on *each* client.

Comment: in the end we solved it with the post-commit hook that checked to see wether a pre-defined set of files were changed and sent a mail to all the devs with a warning. of course it's not as functional, sometimes the changes are harmless, but it's way better than nothing!

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge what you are asking for cannot be accomplished the way you are expecting. As a workaround you can validate the dB schema changes during commits and set a custom property (say svn:isdbchanged) which will hold revision in which the db schema changed. Later during build probably you can display the property from your build script after validating if the last build was performed before the particular revision was updated.

Comment: this is a little too example-specific, the database generation script is just one of the many many cases in which this would be needed, but thanks

Comment: The solution would be to write your own build script or a fetch script which will do the necessary update.